# Centre a long table?

Tags: longtable

```
\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|l|}

\textbf{Test} & \textbf{Input into all tests} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Expected Result\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Actual \end{tabular}} \\ \hline
1 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}x\\ \{[]\}\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}x \end{tabular} & x\\ \hline
\end{longtable}
```

That is the first two rows of my table

However my table is quite wide and at the minute it lines up with the left margin and then is spread to the edge of the page on the right. How do I get the table to sit in the centre of the page?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I'm afraid there are very few (reliable) psychics that frequent this site. You'll need to post an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) to show us what your table contains.

Comment: I've added the first two rows of the table

Comment: Is there any reason for the tabular within `longtable`?

Comment: Two observations: (i) As posted, the `longtable` does *not* exceed the width of the text block, and (ii) many of the cells seem to contain `tabular` environments that don't do anything useful. How can we help?

Comment: @user76135: If you want to center some stuff in a column that is not `c`, use `\multicolumn{1}{c}{some stuff}`, wrapping use a `p` or similar column

Comment: for most document types it is much better to arrange that the table is not wider than the text block rather than making it bleed into the left margin, but can not suggest any ways to achieve that with the small fragment posted.

Comment: I used a table generator to create most of it,as its a big table and was taking ages to type myself,it put in the tabular environments.

Answer (score 3):

Unsure what is really wanted, but some 'improvements' of the table.

Wrapping of text inside a table cell can be achieved with `makecell` package and `\thead` macro.

The `tabular` environments are of no use here and can be replaced by `\multicolumn` statements. I kept the `@{}` stuff, although not useful here (in my point of view)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}



\begin{longtable}{|*{4}{l|}}
\centering
    \textbf{Test} & \textbf{Input into all tests} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Expected Result\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Actual \end{tabular}} \\ \hline
    1 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}x\\ \{[]\}\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}x \end{tabular} & x\\ 
    \hline
    & & & \tabularnewline
    \textbf{Test} & \textbf{Input into all tests} & \multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}|}{\textbf{Expected Result}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Actual}} \\ 
    & & & \tabularnewline
    \hline
    1 & \thead[l]{x \\ \{[]\}} & \multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}|}{x}  & x\\ 
    \hline
  \end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]